# Not able to click on "div" element using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

am working on selecting a date in calender using selenium webdriver commands.

This is my calender path,

```
<div class="xdsoft_datetimepicker xdsoft_noselect xdsoft_" style="display: block; left: 689.4px; top: 247px; position: absolute;">
<div class="xdsoft_datepicker active">
<div class="xdsoft_mounthpicker">
<div class="xdsoft_calendar">
<table>
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week0 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title="" data-year="2016" data-month="10" data-date="13">
<td class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week1 xdsoft_date" title="" data-year="2016" data-month="10" data-date="14">
<td class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date" title="" data-year="2016" data-month="10" data-date="15">
<td class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week3 xdsoft_date" title="" data-year="2016" data-month="10" data-date="16">
<td class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week4 xdsoft_date" title="" data-year="2016" data-month="10" data-date="17">
<td class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week5 xdsoft_date" title="" data-year="2016" data-month="10" data-date="18">
<div>18</div>
</td>
<td class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week6 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title="" data-year="2016" data-month="10" data-date="19">
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Throwing error saying element is not visible.
Please help me access the date element.

Comment: Add your relevant code also

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it worked for me after giving wait command before the xpath